# C# Insert char at cursor position in textbox

Tags: c#, string

I know there are some answers on stackoverflow but when I try it it inserts the text at the begin of text...

I tried

```
string insertText = "$";
int selectionIndex = textBox1.SelectionStart;
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert( selectionIndex, insertText );
```

Comment: And what was `selectionIndex`?

Comment: selectionIndex was the position of my cursor :/

Comment: What was the number? The code works fine.

Comment: I could send pictures

Comment: No, don't "send pictures".

Comment: I want to make that when I enter "$", the symbol is written 2 times and the cursor is between them ...

Comment: But my cursor was at position 8 and selectionIndex too

Comment: _I want to make that when I enter "$", the symbol is written 2 times_ no code that does that. But the selectionStart is moved to the start when you chage the text. So you need to store and restore it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly in what context you are using it, but for me (.NET 4.6.1) this code works fine if used in a button handler, but only after the first click. Changing the text in the `TextBox` seems to reset the cursor position.

So to keep the cursor at its original place you have to set it back to what it was before you inserted the new text:

```
string insertText = "$";
int selectionIndex = textBox1.SelectionStart;
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert( selectionIndex, insertText );
textBox1.SelectionStart = selectionIndex; // restore cursor position
```